# Disk quota exceeded warning in server

Tags: php, wordpress, hosting, quota

i have a question for this warning

> Warning: session_start():
>   open(/tmp/sess_ba3cae26d5ca3bfb594c3424a10fe9c4, O_RDWR) failed: Disk
>   quota exceeded (122) in
>   /home/ericramirez19/public_html/wp-content/plugins/buddypress-media/index.php
>   on line 68

my index page is correct and what things go to this error ?,
Is it server problem or code?
I am using word press so any  solution for word press?

Comment: Have you spoken with your hosting provider? or looked to see what is taking up all your disk quota?

Answer (score 5):

There is another limit as well - `inodes` (number of files allowed), you can check that by command

```
df -i
```

i've found on mine that `/var/lib/php5` contained nearly million files so i've deleted all session files there and problem was solved

```
find /var/lib/php5/ -name "sess_*" -delete
```

Answer (score 4):

The disk quota is the maximum amount of data you're allowed to store in a given disk or location. You should first verify if you're making proper use of your disk space (i.e., do you have thousands of temporary files you no longer need but failed to remove?). If you actually decide you simply need more space, you should contact your hosting provider and upgrade your plan.

In your case, you might consider not using the system-wide temporary directory for session storage.

Comment: i am using word press so if any special things for worpress

Answer (score 2):

I saw that error several times, and the following solution helps me to solve the issue:-

```
1) Deleted unwanted and unnecessary emails (once I have around 57652 unread emails)

2) There is a 'tmp' folder in your root directory, deleted all files from that.

3) File created by you or any of your application which is taking large memory.

4) Remove data from trash
```

**Conclusion  :**
This Issue is because of few files taking more spaces then specified by your hosting provider. So either upgrade your plan or find the culprit file and remove it.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same error when I upload back-up created on my old hosting to my new server. My mistake was to upload archive without opening on my home PC.

So, how I solve such error: I just unzip backup on my PC and **create new zip-archive**. When I **upload files again** to my server the problem was solved.

Answer (score 0):

`du -sch .[!.]* * |sort -h`

use this command in the home directory(e.g. `/usr2`) to check which hidden folders are taking up space.

You can also check if there are package cache. It can be safely removed.

Reference: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/356280/458332

Answer (score -1):

In my case the culprit was emails. The system was clogged with undeleted mails. Once the old mails were deleted, everything became fine.